# iTunes online store architecture

Tags: itunes-store

These are days when many major websites are sharing details about their internal architecture. 
I am curious if anyone has some idea about the architecture of the iTunes online store. 
Is there any published material,video or folklore about the architecture of the iTunes online store?

In particular I would love to know what Apple uses to store so much of the audio and video content.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

AFIK it's one of the few sites that are based on WebObjects (Apple's own framework like PHP).